# Flask .env file read locally but not on server

Tags: python, flask

Of course, my Flask application works in my development environment but not on the server. Here are the relevant files:

```
|- application
|---- __init__.py
|---- config.py
|---- ...
|- wsgi.py
|- .env
```

Here's `wsgi.py`

```
from application import init_app

app = init_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("host=0.0.0.0)
```

Here's `application/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask

def init_app():
    # Initialize the core application
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    # Select and load config object dynamically based on the value of FLASK_ENV in .env
    if app.config["ENV"] == "production":
        app.config.from_object("application.config.ProductionConfig")
    else:
        app.config.from_object("application.config.DevelopmentConfig")

    with app.app_context():
        return app
```

And finally `.env`

```
FLASK_APP=application
FLASK_ENV=development
```

I have verified that on my development machine, changing the value of FLASK_ENV in `.env` works as expected. On the server, it tries running as production regardless of the value. What am I missing?

Edit to add that this is an Ubuntu 20 server on AWS Lightsail if that's important.

Answer (score 1):

`The files are only loaded by the flask command or calling run(). If you would like to load these files when running in production, you should call load_dotenv() manually.` checkout [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/cli/#dotenv)

probably add `flask.cli.load_dotenv()`
and also make sure `python-dotenv` is installed with `pip install python-dotenv`

Comment: Adding "from dotenv import load_dotenv" and "load_dotenv()" to wsgi.py fixed it. It wasn't being loaded when using "flask run" or "python3 wsgi.py" which ultimately calls app.run(), so to your first point, shouldn't it be loaded? Thank you.

Comment: Glad it works! I'm not sure about why it didn't work in the first place, it seems the default value of `load_dotenv` is `True`, in `app.run()`. It probably has something to do with the way wsgi interacts with flask.

Comment: Hello @Hazel ! Did you solve this? Where exactly did you put the `load_dotenv()`? I tried using it inside my `main.py` to see if it fixed the issue, but it did'nt change anything.